# jQuery and Codeigniter - post form with ajax and show result in fancybox

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post, fancybox

I'm using this code to achieve what I said in the title:

```
$("#design-preview").click(function() {

      e.preventDefault();

      var data = $(this).closest("form").serializeArray();

      $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache       : false,
        url         : base_url,
        data        : data,
        success : function(data) {
          $.fancybox(data, {
            'type'  : 'iframe',
            'width' : 340,
            'height': 500
          });
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

The problem is, I get this from firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://domain.info/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%20PUBLIC"
```

It somehow adds the result of the form to the link. 
Does anybody have any idea why is that? Maybe a better suggestion?

EDIT: The response of the ajax post is a HTML page. The HTML code is appended to the link by fancybox, so I guess this narrows a little the research. The post is made correctly, I checked with firebug.

Thank you.

Comment: The url has to point to a file or controller that processes the serialized array of inputs

Comment: @Alfonso: Hello! No, it's a link. I corrected the click handler, altough the post vars were received correctly. I guess jQuery 15 figures takes the form in which the link is placed.

Comment: In firefox, check the output of `console.log(base_url)` and `console.log(data)` before success. base_url is not affected by fancybox **in this code**.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the error lies in the **url: base_url** parameter as the request has invalid url characters you may show the base_url value,or do you mean 
    `<?=base_url();?>`

Comment: Hello! base_url is a javascript variable which stores exactly what base_url() returns. It's set in the head section of the html template.

Comment: @cili: You might want to double-check that. It seems that base_url actually contains some HTML and not the output of CI's `base_url()` function.

Comment: As I said in the edit, the HTML code is appended to the URL by fancybox because I'm trying to show the result (HTML code) into a fancybox. This seems to be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try hard-coding your URL in there just to see if it will work. Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `$(this).serializeArray()` portion of your code. That method is intended for serializing the inputs of a form. I doubt you are 'clicking' a form to trigger the submission.

I'm willing to bet that you are clicking a button within a form to show what something might look like based on the fields of the form... and that is what my example below assumes.

**Try this:**

```
$("#design-preview").click(function() {
  var data = $(this).parent('form').serializeArray();
  $.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    cache       : false,
    url         : 'http://domain.info/foo',
    data        : data,
    success : function(data) {
      $.fancybox(data, {
        'type'  : 'iframe',
        'width' : 340,
        'height': 500
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Lemme know if that works for ya.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, "design-preview" is in fact a link. I corrected the handler function, but the problem is that fancybox adds this the HTML result of the ajax call to the link. Any suggestions about that? Thank you.